# How to declare a variable global in a lambda function?

Tags: python

I have a below defined function:

```
x = 5

def foo():
    global x
    x = x * 2
    return x

foo()
```

Output: `10`

Executing the above function `foo()` returns `10` and also updates the value of `x` as `10` since `x` is defined as `global` variable.

I want to achieve the same task using `lambda` function. How can I declare `x` as my global variable inside a `lambda` function?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Using global variables is generally a bad idea and it's unclear why you want a lambda that modifies one

Comment: 100% agree. It is out of the curiosity to know how global variable can be used and accessed lambda function.

Comment: You can't do an assignment in a `lambda` function, so the question is moot (and a duplicate).